# Connecting two laptops through wireless adapters without wireless router

Tags: windows-xp, wifi, laptop

I want to connect two laptops through their wireless network adapters. I dont want to use any wireless router or access point. How can I do that. Both are running windows xp, where one has sp2 and other has sp3. I am looking around internet but unable to get solution.

I also tried this way described by Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/bowman_02april08.mspx but unable to establish. Can you people guide me this process.

Thanks.

Comment: What problems are you encoutering?  Both cards should be set for the same Ad-Hoc (not infrastructure) network in their wireless configuration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx

It's called Ad-Hoc wireless networking and it can be used to connect PCs to each other (and to the internet via ICS) without a router.

Answer (score 0):

andrewd18 has the best information link on how to set it up.  The only drawback I remember i had last time I did this was that the network speed was limited to 11mb when using an ad hoc network. Maybe this has improved since then? Otherwise it worked great for me.

Comment: If i remember right, it depends on your hardware/driver whether 802.11b or g is available in ad-hoc mode. Even if g works in infrastructure mode it can be limited to b in ad-hoc mode.